# mod_rewrite rules aren't working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've already been in contact with my webhosting and they've been, somewhat, less than helpful, so I've come to the geniuses here.

I'm unable to rewrite any of my URLs on my website, via the .htaccess file.

I only have one .htaccess file, which is in the root of my home directory. Here is that file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# The support guys thought it was in issue with the L flag below, so I commented out my original implementation and used their supplied one

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mythofechelon.co.uk$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mythofechelon.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(([a-z0-9_]+\.)?mythofechelon\.co.uk)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


RewriteRule ^/$ /main/pages/index.php?home
RewriteRule ^/home(.*)?$ /main/pages/index.php?home
RewriteRule ^/404(.*)?$ /main/pages/index.php?404

#I will eventually change the following commands to link to the rewritten URLs when this all eventually works
DirectoryIndex /main/pages/index.php?home
ErrorDocument 404 /main/pages/index.php?404

AddType application/x-shockwave-flash swf

Options All -Indexes

#Protect .htaccess
<files .htaccess>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</files>

<Files *.reg>
    ForceType application/pdf
    Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</Files>

#Block bots
<limit GET POST HEAD>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    Deny from env=bad_bot
</limit>

RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Anarchie [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ASPSeek [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^attach [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^autoemailspider [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^BlackWidow [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Bot\ mailto:craftbot@yahoo.com [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ChinaClaw [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Custo [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^DISCo [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Download\ Demon [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^eCatch [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EirGrabber [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailSiphon [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailWolf [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Express\ WebPictures [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ExtractorPro [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EyeNetIE [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^FlashGet [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetRight [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetWeb! [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Go!Zilla [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Go-Ahead-Got-It [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GrabNet [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Grafula [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^HMView [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} HTTrack [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Image\ Stripper [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Image\ Sucker [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Indy\ Library [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^InterGET [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Internet\ Ninja [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^JetCar [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^JOC\ Web\ Spider [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^larbin [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^LeechFTP [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mass\ Downloader [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^MIDown\ tool [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mister\ PiX [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Navroad [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NearSite [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetAnts [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetSpider [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Net\ Vampire [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetZIP [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Octopus [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Offline\ Explorer [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Offline\ Navigator [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^PageGrabber [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Papa\ Foto [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pavuk [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pcBrowser [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^RealDownload [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ReGet [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SiteSnagger [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SmartDownload [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SuperBot [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SuperHTTP [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Surfbot [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^tAkeOut [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Teleport\ Pro [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^VoidEYE [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Image\ Collector [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Sucker [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebAuto [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebCopier [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebFetch [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebGo\ IS [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebLeacher [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebReaper [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebSauger [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ eXtractor [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ Quester [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebStripper [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebWhacker [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebZIP [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Wget [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Widow [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WWWOFFLE [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Xaldon\ WebSpider [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Xenu [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Zeus.*Webster [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Zeus 

SetEnvIfNoCase user-Agent ^FrontPage [NC,OR]
SetEnvIfNoCase user-Agent ^Java.* [NC,OR]
SetEnvIfNoCase user-Agent ^Microsoft.URL [NC,OR]
SetEnvIfNoCase user-Agent ^MSFrontPage [NC,OR]
SetEnvIfNoCase user-Agent ^Offline.Explorer [NC,OR]
SetEnvIfNoCase user-Agent ^[Ww]eb[Bb]andit [NC,OR]
SetEnvIfNoCase user-Agent ^Zeus [NC]
```

(Man, you guys need to change it so that you don't have to manually indent every single line.)

I have independently confirmed that:

- The `DirectoryIndex` command is working, as `DirectoryIndex /main/pages/index.php` works.
- The `ErrorDocument 404` command is working, obviously.
- Linking to files using PHP variables works, as the current implementations of the `DirectoryIndex` and `ErrorDocument 404` commands work.
- It is not an issue with any of the file-protecting or bot-blocking commands.
- It is not an issue with the "www." removing commands, as I have commented out and completely removed all attempted implementations of them and still had the same issues.

The issue lies, seemingly, entirely with the `RewriteRule` commands. `RewriteEngine` is enabled, at least in the .htaccess and `mod_rewrite` was working a few days ago, before I restarted my site.

I'm thinking that it may be because the `RewriteRule`s have no `RewriteCond`s, but these exact commands were working a few days ago.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]` stops _all_ rewriting and gives a 403, is that what you want... And you can indent blocks of text with the `{}` key :P

Comment: I would say possibly, but I think that was originally commented out. And it's after the `RewriteRule` commands that I need working? Oh, thank you for the `{}` tip! My God, that has always been annoying. :L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the .htaccess you posted above, there is no RewriteRule immediately following these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

So they will be combined with the next uncommented rules which does the redirect but does not define what file should handle these requests:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(([a-z0-9_]+\.)?mythofechelon\.co.uk)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

You'll want something like this:

```
# Strip www. from domain name 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Send requests for non-existent files and directories to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^home/(.*)$ /main/pages/index.php?$1 [L]
```

Order of rules is essential with mod_rewrite. Another example in your file where things are out of order is the section where you're trying to block bad bots. The `RewriteRule` must come after the `RewriteCond` rules.  Also, your limit section doesn't actually do anything since none of the rules about the bots actually set the environment variable.

There's actually another directive you can use specifically for looking at user agents and setting environment variables: `BrowserMatch` and `BrowserMatchNoCase` - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html#browsermatchnocase.

I'd replace the lines for the bad bots with something like this:

```
BrowserMatchNoCase Anarchie bad_bot
```

Then move your limit section below the `BrowserMatchNoCase` entries -- otherwise the environment variable may not be set yet.

Also, mod_rewrite flags are not valid with `SetEnvIfNoCase` entries.

**Update**

To handle the 404s you could either add the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^!home/(.*)$ /main/pages/index.php?404 [L]
```

Or (**and this is what I would suggest**) you could change home to .* and then update your php script to send the 404 when appropriate.

Comment: Thank you. That has fixed the issue. However, it seems `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /main/pages/index.php?$1 [L]` acts in a `ErrorDocument 404` manner, but appends the "bad URL" to `index.php?`. I don't want this to happen. I only want "/home" available as a rewritten URL (for now) and everything else sent to "/404". Is there a way to do this? And yes, the support technician gave me a new bot-blocking system that functions like the one you've suggested. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I've edited my post to address these issues. You'd just need to tweak the RewriteRule and keep your ErrorDocument as it was.

Comment: I guess ErrorDocument takes precedence over RewriteRules then. See my latest update.

Comment: I re-reviewed your comments and answer and then had another look at my old, working .htaccess and I've figured it out for myself now. What should I do now? I want to give you the correct answer for being helpful and leading me to think of the solution, but it's not _actually_ the "correct answer". So, should I post my own solution and give that the correct answer?

Comment: It's really up to you, but it seems to me that if my answer lead to the solution it would be appropriate to accept it as correct. You could also post another answer with additional details/info. Your call..